# DNS, keep all settings but the 'A' record

Tags: dns, office365

My domain manager is Office 365.

I want it to keep all the current records, but as my website is in another server, I have pointed the 'A' record to my website server IP.

My question is, will my website DNS manager override my domain manager records that are in Office 365 (Office 365 manages the domain)? Or my domain manager will ignore the records set in the website DNS manager?

I ask that because I want to keep all my emails records from Office 365, and only point my domain to the website hosting server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS works in a cascading system starting with the root nameservers. They then go down to the TLD nameservers followed by the authoritative nameservers.

The authoritative nameservers are where all of your DNS records reside (your DNS zone, in other words). Whatever records are found in this zone are the ones that are used when someone tries to resolve a DNS record for your domain.

Because of this, your zone needs to contain all of your DNS records in a single place. This means that you can't have an authoritative zone managed in Office 365 and your host's domain manager. You will need to use one or the other and ensure that all of the records that you want are there.

Comment: So what is happening now? If I point just an 'A' record to my website server IP, will my email settings from Office 365 remain working? Because my domain manager is Office 365, and I have only pointed the record 'A' to the website IP server, but it happens that the website that is in another server also have created DNS records, but the website from this server is not my domain manager.

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that your DNS provider is godaddy and you have configured Office 365 to manage DNS for you. This basically means that Office 365 has authorisation to sign into godaddy and alter records on your behalf.

In this case, any addditional records you add to the domain, other than the ones that Office 365 has configured won't be touched by Office 365.